# devise register routes rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

My devise routes are:

```
devise_scope :user do
    get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
    get "/register" => "devise/registrations#new"
end
```

And my Devise Registration from is:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

<div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

But the form tag is rendered as:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/" class="user_new" id="user_new" method="post">
```

I think, however, it should be the register controller.

Any ideas?

Thanks y'all,

j

Comment: How did you generate the views? Usually you use `rails generate devise:views users` to create them and customize them to your needs from there.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you're missing the `:to` argument. It should be:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "/login", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
  get "/logout", :to => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  get "/register", :to => "devise/registrations#new"
end
```